# VBA Arrays and Loops

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I am having trouble with looping through my already defined array to find values that are over 500. It is telling me that my subscript is out of range.

This is what I have so far. Can someone help me to fix the second part, so it will properly loop through the already established arrays.

```
Sub hishSale()

    Dim customers() As String
    Dim sale() As String
    Dim hiCustomer() As String
    Dim hiSale() As String
    Dim nCustomers As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim isOver As Integer


    'capture the number of customers and sales and put them in two seperate arrays
    With wsData.Range("A3")
        nCustomers = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        ReDim customers(nCustomers)
        ReDim sale(nCustomers)
        For i = 1 To nCustomers
            customers(i) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
            sale(i) = .Offset(i, 1).Value
        Next
    End With

'Loop through arrays to find sales over $500

    With Range("A3")
    isOver = 0
        For i = 1 To nCustomers
            If .Offset(i, 1).Value > 500 Then
                isOver = isOver + 1
                hiCustomer(isOver) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
                hiSale(isOver) = .Offset(isOver, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With

    'return results in columns D and E
    With Range("D3")
        For i = 1 To nCustomers
        .Offset(i, 0) = hiCustomer(isOver)
        .Offset(i, 1) = hiSale(isOver)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: To loop array do `for lbound(customers()) to ubound(customers())`

Comment: In your final loop maybe you meant to use `i` to index into `hiCustomer` and `hiSale` ?  You're using `isOver`, the value of which is fixed at this point

Comment: You need to indicate exactly which line has the error...

Comment: Seems like you didn't like any of these [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451055/vba-filing-arrays-and-creating-columns/37453459#37453459). What was wrong with them? This time are you going to give some feedback to pepole who are willing to dedicate time to problems you throw in here?

Comment: The line that has a problem is: 

   `With Range("D3")
        For i = 1 To nCustomers
        .Offset(i, 0) = hiCustomer(isOver)
        .Offset(i, 1) = hiSale(isOver)
        Next
    End With`

**`.Offset(i, 0) = hiCustomer(isOver)`** --- is giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to write a big description an walk through about your arrays being bigger then needed and how they have a base of zero, while doing so I found the problem was you never dimension `hiCustomer` OR `hiSale`.

Change this: -

```
'Loop through arrays to find sales over $500
With Range("A3")
isOver = 0
    For i = 1 To nCustomers
        If .Offset(i, 1).Value > 500 Then
            isOver = isOver + 1
            hiCustomer(isOver) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
            hiSale(isOver) = .Offset(isOver, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

To this: -

```
ReDim hiCustomer(0)
ReDim hiSale(0)
With Range("A3")
    For i = 1 To nCustomers
        If .Offset(i, 1).Value > 500 Then
            ReDim Preserve hiCustomer(UBound(hiCustomer, 1) + 1)
            ReDim Preserve hiSale(UBound(hiSale, 1) + 1)
            hiCustomer(UBound(hiCustomer, 1)) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
            hiSale(UBound(hiCustomer, 1)) = .Offset(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

And if I am reading it correct the next loop will also need changing to: -

```
'return results in columns D and E
With Range("D3")
    For i = 1 To UBound(hiCustomer)
        .Offset(i, 0) = hiCustomer(i)
        .Offset(i, 1) = hiSale(i)
    Next
End With
```

Previously it was looking the customer list and not just the >500 list.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Is there a way you can write the code without using Ubound?

Comment: @th65 yes but it would be longer. Add it is a new question and I'm sure someone will help. I'm curious as to the why.